# Is a linear mixed model analyzing my data correctly?

Tags: regression, model, linear

My data look like this:

```
      X              Nest  Class Group  BCI
1     1  CC-061818-6AS-JB  Med_A     A 2.16
2     2  CC-061818-6AS-JB  Med_A     A 2.12
3     3  CC-061818-6AS-JB  Med_A     A 2.13
48   48  CC-061918-5AS-JB  Low_A     A 2.44
49   49  CC-061918-5AS-JB  Low_A     A 2.50
50   50  CC-061918-5AS-JB  Low_A     A 2.52
51   51  CC-061918-8AS-JB  Med_A     A 2.52
```

There are 7 classes: Low_A, Med_A, High_A, Low_C, Med_C, High_C, and NTC

Each nest received the same treatment, and each nest can have up to 10 individual BCI measurements. I used a linear mixed model with Nest as a random effect and Class as a fixed effect. I want to know if there is a difference in BCI among the groups, and if so, which groups are different.

I did an LMER in R and a likelihood ratio test to determine if Class was a significant effect. Is this all I need to do? Here is my code and results:

```
#create linear mixed model with Class as fixed variable and Nest as a random variable 
LMER <- lmer(BCI ~ Class + (1|Nest), data = Data, REML = FALSE)
#Create null model [without effect of Class]
LMER_Null <- lmer(BCI ~ (1|Nest), data = Data, REML = FALSE)
#Check residuals
plot(LMER)
#use ANOVA to perform likelihood ratio test to determine if Class is significant
Anova <- anova(LMER_Null, LMER)
#Print results
Anova

Data: Data
Models:
LMER_Null: BCI ~ (1 | Nest)
LMER: BCI ~ Class + (1 | Nest)
          Df     AIC     BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
LMER_Null  3 -314.01 -301.64  160.0  -320.01                           
LMER       9 -312.80 -275.68  165.4  -330.80 10.788      6    0.09516 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I ask because when I do this with all groups combined, I get a nonsignificant result (which is what I want/expect). But when I subset the data and do it with just the High_C, Med_C, and Low_C classes, I get a significant result. How could this be?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Do you want to test for class or group? And if you want to test for group, why is it not in your model? Kindly explain the setup of the experiment a bit better.

Comment: How strong are the "C-only" results? Even if there is no underlying effect, hey could have appeared due to chance. When dealing with multiple tests in the same study, please be aware that p-values have to be readjusted in order to maintain the same global false positive ratio (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction )

Comment: I want to test for Class. I was testing for the effect of a pesticide on turtle nests. "Class" is the amount and type of treatment (High_A = high levels of pesticide A, Low_C = low levels of control substance C). "Group" was for other analyses.

The C-only results are not very strong, p = 0.04689.

Thanks again!